# Vector bundles on elliptic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a stable vector bundle of degree $d$ and rank $r$, with $(r,d)$ coprime and $X$ an elliptic curve. I know that I can construct an extension 
$$0 \to H^0(F) \otimes O_X \to G \to F \to 0 $$
such that the boundary map of the associated long sequence in cohomology is given by $Id: H^0(F) \to H^0(F)$. Now  know that G is a vector bundle of rank $r+d$ and degree $d$. What I'd like to do is proving that $G$ is stable (here I have problems), because it'll let me proceed by induction with the computation of $M(r,d)$.

Answer (score 1):

edit: I'm guessing, since you say there is an induced LES, that you mean the sequence is exact. Note there is an isomorphism between U(r,d) and U(r+d,d) given by [4.9](http://www.tufts.edu/~mteixido/files/vectbund.pdf) which is giving you the extension (the proof there does the isomorphism starting from the other direction however). In any case, assuming this is how you get the extension, $G$ is indecomposable. 
Now an indecomposable vector bundle on an elliptic curve is stable iff $(r,d)=1$ by [4.19](http://www.tufts.edu/~mteixido/files/vectbund.pdf). Now since $(r,d) = 1$, then $k | (r + d) \implies (k, r) = (k, d) = 1$ so any divisors of $\ r + d$ cannot divide $\ d$ so $(r + d, d) = 1$

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. Now, I know that it is sufficient to prove that $G$ is indecomposable because $r$ and $r+d$ are coprime. But what I can't understand is the reason why $G$ is indecomposable. Why does this extension force $G$ to be indecomposable. And, is it true that $H^0(F) \otimes O_X$ is semistable?

Comment: (1) As far as I can tell, $G$ does not have to be indecomposable, if you compare with the last paragraph or two of $4.9$ proof mentioned above. For the second question, I think you can just use the slope criterion and look at subbundles of $O_X^d$ which should be $O_X^{e<d}$, since they all have degree zero, then it should be semistable. Finally, I think you would usually do the classification by first doing indecomposables, and then saying that decomposables are direct sums of these.