# Extensions of Vector Bundles on Elliptic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles

In this question [Vector bundles on elliptic curves](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/739359/vector-bundles-on-elliptic-curves#739817) the author states that for $F$ a stable vector bundle of degree $d$ and rank $r$, with $(r,d)$ coprime and $X$ an elliptic curve one can construct an extension
$$0 \to H^0(F) \otimes O_X \to G \to F \to 0 $$
such that the boundary map of the associated long sequence in cohomology is given by $Id: H^0(F) \to H^0(F)$. Furthermore,  G is a vector bundle of rank $r+d$ and degree $d$.

I do not see why this is true.

I do know that showing $G$ exists is the same as showing that $H^1(F^{\lor} \otimes H^0(F) \otimes \mathcal{O}_X)$ is non-trivial.